# Bitnami RedMine mysql service not restarting

Tags: redmine

I have a redmine project management system setup on my windows server on MYSQL DB.

I had some issues when tried to restart the redmineMysql service and as  per a article on stackoverflow, I deleted the service from registry and recreated the service using 'sc create redmineMYSQL binpath= "D:\Bitnami\redmine-2.6.0-1\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe"'

Now when I try to restart the service I get a error "error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

the time in which the service is restarting, for around 20-25 seconds my mysql is up and available to redmine but then post the error message the mysql goes down again.

Comment: What happens if you try restarting it via bitnami console?

Comment: could not restart, it says..starting...and then stopped.

Comment: Is migrating to new machine option for you?

Comment: No.Actually its our server and migration is not an option.

Comment: But you can migrate to new "your server" ?

Comment: if someone has red mine installed in your machine, please share the configuration for redmineSQL in registry regarding the ImagePath and all.I feel while recreating the service, I might have made a mistake in configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImagePath looks like this:

```
 "C:\BitNami\REDMIN~1.2-0\apache2\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

It is of **REG_EXPAND_SZ** under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\redmineApache`

As for mysql:

This is how default **serviceinstall.bat** looks like, from: `Binami/redmine-2.3.2.-0/mysql/scripts`

```
@echo off
rem -- Check if argument is INSTALL or REMOVE

if not ""%1"" == ""INSTALL"" goto remove

"C:\BitNami\redmine-2.4.2-0/mysql\bin\mysqld.exe" --install "redmineMySQL" --defaults-file="C:\BitNami\redmine-2.4.2-0/mysql\my.ini"

net start "redmineMySQL" >NUL
goto end

:remove
rem -- STOP SERVICES BEFORE REMOVING

net stop "redmineMySQL" >NUL
"C:\BitNami\redmine-2.4.2-0/mysql\bin\mysqld.exe" --remove "redmineMySQL"

:end
exit
```